# Would like to know how a table is populated

Tags: t-sql

Good morning!

I am using TSQL, there is one table that was created years back by another empolyee, I am not sure how this table is populated? I checked the dependencies and it just gives the name of table. I want to know how the columns/data get populated in that table for example. "Freight.load" is the table name.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without any information. Dependencies won't show any applications, agent jobs or scheduled tasks that use the table.

Comment: You can use Extended Events to capture statements that target this table. You can use filters to capture only events that target the table. You can also include details like the application's name in the captured trace

Comment: I tried creating a trace for a whole day for that table, but it never gave me any results ..may be is it because it is not creating any records recently. the table is being populated every day though, but not sure where the data comes for the table...

Comment: @suki How do you know it is being populated every day then?

Comment: It was stored procedure. I found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a trace will catch the inserts. Or you could check who has insert permissions on the table.